# Where are mixins implemented in Rubinius?

Tags: ruby, rubinius

Where in the Rubinius source is the code that is responsible for including modules?(Specifically, to place module as super class of object class.)

Comment: I'm afraid it is placed in vm/builtin/* and is written in cpp.

Comment: You underestimate the coolness of Rubinius :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`Module#include`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Module%3ainclude), you’ll find that it delegates to `Module#append_features`:

> Invokes `Module.append_features` on each parameter in reverse order.

The documentation for [`Module#append_features`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Module%3aappend_features), in turn, describes (very briefly) how the default Ruby mixin algorithm works:

> When this module is included in another, Ruby calls `append_features` in this module, passing it the receiving module in `mod`. Ruby’s default implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to `mod` if this module has not already been added to `mod` or one of its ancestors. See also [`Module#include`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Module%3ainclude).

If you look at [`Module#append_features`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L164-171) in the [Rubinius sourcecode](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/), you’ll find that it is an alias for `Module#include_into`:

> ```
> # Called when this Module is being included in another Module.
> # This may be overridden for custom behaviour. The default
> # is to add constants, instance methods and module variables
> # of this Module and all Modules that this one includes to +klass+.
> #
> # See also #include.
> #
> alias_method :append_features, :include_into
> ```

So, finally, [`Module#include_into`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L86-162) is the real deal:

> ```
> # Add all constants, instance methods and module variables
> # of this Module and all Modules that this one includes to +klass+
> #
> # This method is aliased as append_features as the default implementation
> # for that method. Kernel#extend calls this method directly through
> # Module#extend_object, because Kernel#extend should not use append_features.
> def include_into(klass)
>   ...
> ```

Your specific question:

> exactly to place module as super class of object class

is answered in [this loop](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L120-137):

> ```
> k = klass.direct_superclass
> while k
>   if k.kind_of? Rubinius::IncludedModule
>     # Oh, we found it.
>     if k == mod
>       # ok, if we're still within the directly included modules
>       # of klass, then put future things after mod, not at the
>       # beginning.
>       insert_at = k unless superclass_seen
>       add = false
>       break
>     end
>   else
>     superclass_seen = true
>   end
>
>   k = k.direct_superclass
> end
> ```

Watch for [`insert_at`](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/module.rb#L100).